# Intellij is not getting started on VM machine

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am unable to open intellij on my VM machine, however when I clicked over the Intellij icon from Start menu, it shows the start image of Intellij but does not showing anything after that and also in task manager its not showing any kind of process Intellij is also not throwing any kind of error

Comment: Check [the log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors, try starting using `idea.bat` to see if there are any errors printed in the console.

Comment: Thanks for replying and the issue has been resolved now as there was a change in the vmoptions file in bin folder. I updated the settings to default.